# Scan error on column index 0, name \"ID\": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *[]authService.Permission"

Tags: mysql, go, call

I am getting the below error when I try to call `err = row.Scan(&resourceList, resourceTypeId)`

> Scan error on column index 0, name "ID": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *[]authService.Permission"

```
type Permission struct {
    ID               int    `json:"id"`
    Name             string `json:"name"`
    Description      string `json:"description"`
    ParentResourceID int    `json:"parentResourceId"`
}

func GetResourcesByResourceTypeId(resourceTypeId string) ([]Permission, string, error) {
db, ctx := db.GetDB()
query := "CALL usp_GetParentResourceListByResourceTypeID(?)"
var resourceList []Permission
stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
defer stmt.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Errorln("Error in preparing statement. " + err.Error())
    return nil, "Error in preparing statement.", err
}

row := stmt.QueryRowContext(ctx, resourceTypeId)

err = row.Scan(&resourceList, resourceTypeId)
if err == nil {
    return resourceList, "Resource retrieval.", nil
}

log.Warningln("Resource retrieval failed, ResourceTypeID: " + resourceTypeId + ".")
return resourceList, "Resource retrieval failed.", nil
}
```

SQL Returns below

```
ID  Name
15  Applications
16  Subscriptions
17  Payments
```

The same query works fine when I try to use SQL Server with `EXEC` statement in the `query`.

Any idea on whats wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Firstly [`QueryRowContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.5#Conn.QueryRowContext)

> executes a query that is expected to return at most one row

Your question indicates that your statement returns multiple results so this is not the right function to use (`QueryContext` would be more appropriate).

The second issue is as stated in the error:

> unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *[]authService.Permission"

The first column in the result set is an integer (probably the value `15` in this case) and you are trying to scan that into a `[]Permission`. If you changed
`var resourceList []Permission` to `var resourceList int` that error would be fixed (but the second parameter also needs work).

Take a look at [this example](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18.5#example-DB.QueryContext) in the documentation. Taking that code and applying it to your situation will result in something like the following (untested; just intended to point you in the right direction):

```
rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "CALL usp_GetParentResourceListByResourceTypeID(?)", resourceTypeId)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

var resourceList []Permission

for rows.Next() {
    var resource Permission
    if err := rows.Scan(&resource.ID, &resource.Name); err != nil {
        // Check for a scan error.
        // Query rows will be closed with defer.
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resourceList = append(resourceList, resource )
}

rerr := rows.Close()
if rerr != nil {
    log.Fatal(rerr)
}

if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

**Note:** Your structure `Permission` contains four elements but the query returns two columns so I'm not really sure how you intend to fill the other two (or what the mapping is).